# Rotación de la cámara en three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Lamentablemente no tengo el código presente pero trataré de explicar lo más detallado posible:

Estoy creando un pequeño juego en `three.js` y he hecho que la cámara rote (en el eje `y`) al mover el cursor hacia la izquierda o la derecha.

He hecho lo mismo con el eje (`x`) al mover de arriba hacia abajo y todo funciona bien mientras no rote la cámara en el eje (`y`). El problema es que si roto la cámara 90 grados en el eje `y` al rotar un poco el eje `x` no moverá hacia arriba o abajo como es de esperar.

En pocas palabras, cuando roto la cámara los ejes de rotación no lo hacen y eso da ese problema.

¿Que debería hacer?

PD: más o menos cuando roto la cámara en eje `y` 90 grados la rotación `x` es parecida a la rotación en eje `z`, por eso sí roto la cámara 180 grados en el mismo eje si funciona.

*ya que no tengo el código espero que me borren la pregunta :<*

Comment: Puede que encuentres algo aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926273/13003076

Comment: Y cómo sabes que no funciona si no tienes código? Por favor crea un [mre].

Comment: @Mateo el código no lo he podido poner aquí pero he encontrado una solución

Comment: Probablemente, no te dejó poner el código por que era muy extenso. La proxima te recomiendo tomarte el tiempo de leer el link que te pasó mateo y reescribir tu código para que sea acorde a lo indicado.

Answer (score 0):

Con un poco de matemática y la función `camera.lookAt()` se soluciona todo ;)

Para más información dirigirse [aquí](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt)

Comment: Yo creo que con [setRotationFromEuler](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.setRotationFromEuler) es más simple. `lookAt` es más útil cuando quieres que la cámara apunte un punto específico del mundo.